# how can I count the amount of a specific type of file in a directory

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to figure out a way to count the amount of specific file in a directory, lets say for instance I have a directory with

```
hi-austin.txt goodbye-austin.txt cya-austin.txt hey-austin.txt
```

and I wanted to count the amount of files that fit this specification, *-austin.txt, normally I would use the bash function find for this, but I am looking for a C alternative to this an am sort of confused as to how I should go about doing this, any help would really be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: the platform is debian squeeze

Comment: Use readdir to list the contents of a directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

- [`opendir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) and [`readdir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) to access the file names in a current directory
- to check if a filename ends with a particular string:

  ```
  int ends_with(const char* const a_str,
                const char* const a_search_str)
  {
      const size_t str_len    = strlen(a_str);
      const size_t search_len = strlen(a_search_str);

      return str_len > search_len &&
             0 == strcmp(a_search_str, &a_str[str_len - search_len]);
  }
  ```

Comment: `strstr()` isn't really what you need to test for a string ending in `-austin.txt`